# Can't Launch Exec Task from Ant

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant

I am trying to execute a separate function from an ant script and keep getting

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:314)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:244)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
        ... 58 more
```

I eventually want to call Docker but to simplify it I am simply trying to call echo.

My exec block looks like this

```
 <exec failonerror="true" vmlauncher="false" executable="/usr/bin/echo">
      <arg value="testing" />
  </exec>
```

I have tried with vmlauncher true and false and get variations on the same error.

Outside of ant I can run echo no problem, but here is what ls -al says about it
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root       35120 Feb  7  2022  echo`

I'm testing this on an Ubuntu WSL 2 container, but have had similar issues on an Amazon Linux image.

Comment: “Outside of ant I can run echo no problem…” Are you running it as `echo some text` or as `/usr/bin/echo some text`?  The former is almost certainly using the shell’s built-in echo command rather than the /usr/bin/echo executable.

Comment: I was just using echo as you suspected, but just tested with ```/usr/bin/echo test``` and it worked no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out today. I'm running on a custom jre and had only enabled run permission on the bin directory. There must be something in a different subdirectory that is required, because if I give execute permission on the whole jre it works properly.